# Webdatarocks content disappear after clicked apply in field toolbar, then apply button in Fields disable

Tags: webdatarocks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A9vO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl8Dh.png)

webdatarocks content disappear after clicked apply in Fields toolbar. Appreciate someone could help. Thanks

error can reproduce same as link below.
https://www.webdatarocks.com/demos/javascript-pivot-grid-demo/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that they released new 1.4.2 version a day ago - https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdatarocks. Have you tried it?

Comment: I tested just now, it restore. Thanks